# Extending window object with Math's methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, math

Why does jQuery's extend fail when I try to extend `window` with `window.Math`?

Both are Objects by type, as [jQuery accepts them to be](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

```
$.extend( window , window.Math );
```

The main goal would be to get all `Math` functions and constants out into the `window` object for usage like:

```
floor( 9.4 )   // -> 9
PI             // -> 3.141592653589793
max( 1 , 3 )   // -> 3
```

( Without typing `Math.` over and over. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.extend` can only extend **enumerable** properties, while those properties in `Math` object are not enumerable.

For example let's take a look at `Math.PI`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Math, 'PI')
```

It outputs:

```
Object {value: 3.141592653589793, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

That means you cannot retrieve `PI` property by iterating `Math` object. So do other properties. Eventually your approach just equals to:

```
$.extend(window, {});
```

For more information about the descriptors, read this [**doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description).

Comment: Really great answer! Please, append Your approach ( if You have one ) achieving the main goal as well!

Comment: @StevenPalinkas Honestly, I don't think it's a good idea to copy these properties to global object, it's confusing. For example `Math.log()` returns natural logarithm of a number. But what does `log()` do? Is it something similar as `console.log()`? I think it may make code less readable.

Comment: Yeah, You are right - in general, but for a project specifically based on math computations, it is pretty handy.